# Error when running Python ChatBot Code

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am trying to create a ChatBot using chattertbot and when I run this code I'm getting this traceback

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with 

sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: It looks like this is a networking error of some kind. The stack trace you posted shows that it is some kind of ssl error with `urllib`. Perhaps someone could offer assistance if you described your setup or the configuration of your ChatBot.

Comment: Can you post your code that generated this error? It looks like where you wanted to post the code, you posted the error message.